# Create a script to auto log me onto a website accessed by an IP url including the "click OK to logon"

Tags: javascript, c++, html, authentication, auto

I am trying to create a JavaScript/HTML/or C++ that will automatically press an OK button on a window when logging onto an IP via a browser. Basically, if I wanted to automatically log in to a site with a cookie filling in my username and password, the JavaScript would automatically press the OK button that pops up in the separate log in window without me having to do it.

Comment: Your title is not human-parsable.

Answer (score 0):

To not click anything, you'd need to have it in an iframe of another page that has your script in it.  You "should" then be able to access the iframe from your script, access the DOM, and click the button.  Once clicked, you can probably then make it the parent page.  I've never attempted this, so not sure it all works, just about the only way I can think of that might work.

Comment: So i have a main page that has a script cycling IP address pages that all require one login. So you are saying that i would have to create a frame in the first main page and create a script in that frame that accesses the DOM to click the logon button for me?